# How to use a string function argument to subset a data frame within that function

Tags: r

I would like to write a reusable function whose input parameters would be the dataframe and the names of columns i want to subset it with.

The function is defined as below:

```
funct <- function(df, colnames){
  df_subset = df[ , colnames]
   return(df_subset) }

flights_subset <- funct(flights, c("MONTH","YEAR") ) #1st arg is a df, 2nd arg is a string
```

To give more clarity, i have given code to create the input file 'flights'  and the returned file i am expecting from the function 'flights_subset'

```
flights <- structure(list(YEAR = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L), MONTH = c(1L, 
                                                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), DAYOFMONTH = 1:5, DAYOFWEEK = c(6L, 7L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                              2L, 3L), DEPTIME = c(1400L, 1401L, 1352L, 1403L, 1405L)), .Names = c("YEAR", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   "MONTH", "DAYOFMONTH", "DAYOFWEEK", "DEPTIME"), row.names = 5424:5428, class = "data.frame")

flights_subset <- structure(list(MONTH = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), YEAR = c(2011L, 
                                                                     2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L)), .Names = c("MONTH", "YEAR"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 5424:5428)
```

Comment: Your function looks okay. try `funct(mtcars, c('mpg','cyl') )`.

Comment: Thanks Chirayu. Also, could you tell me if i stored the columns to subset on in a string, could i use that string as the function input argument. Eg: b <- "c('MONTH','YEAR')"..and use b as the 2nd arg for the function.

Comment: Dont you think thats worth a try, anyways you created a string wrong. you should do something like this `b <- c('mpg','cyl')` since you want a vector of string.

Answer (score 1):

Your version is fine, you just need to fix the typo in `function`. Also, there's no need for a return statement.

```
funct <- function(df, colnames){
   df[ , colnames] 
}
```

or you can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)   

funct <- function(df, colnames){
df %>% select_(colnames)
 }


flights_subset <- funct(flights, c("MONTH", "YEAR"))
```